# Not able to run app on an iOS 5.1.1 device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I'm developing an iPhone app targeted to iOS 5.1, and it performs well when running on an real iPhone device with such iOS version, but it doesn't when deployed on an iPhone with 5.1.1 version. It seems to be correctly installed, but when run not even GUI is displayed, it looks like it attempts to launch the app but it crashes. I have Xcode 4.5 and I've found nothing about an iOS 5.1.1 SDK, should I update the app to iOS 6.0? How could I solve this?

EDIT: I get this log when running on the device:

```
Nov 19 16:35:29 unknown SpringBoard[605] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 744: (os/kern) failure
Nov 19 16:35:29 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:TA.MyTestApp[0x9d15]) Exited: Killed: 9
Nov 19 16:35:30 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:TA.MyTestApp[0x9d15]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Nov 19 16:35:30 unknown SpringBoard[605] <Warning>: Application 'MyTestApp' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Nov 19 16:35:30 unknown sandboxd[745] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [sandboxd] (690.10)
Nov 19 16:35:30 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: Sandbox: hook..execve() killing pid 744: (err=22) unable to set the builtin profile: container
```

Comment: You could start googling for the error that it gives you when it crashes.

Comment: 1. Have you set the Deployment Target to 5 and not 6.0 ?
2. Are you using something iOS 6 specific only ?

Comment: No, I've the deployment target set to iOS 5.1, and I'm not making use of anything iOS 6 specific...